# Editing world-flags output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, customization, helpermethods

I am trying to edit the output on the world-flags gem, in the documentation it says the following:

You can customize the output by the flag view helper methods:

```
WorldFlags.flag_list_tag = :div
WorldFlags.flag_tag = :span
WorldFlags.flag_text = ''
```

I have tried many things but can't seem to get it to work, where abouts should i place these methods to customise output? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to edit the output of the world flags gem by using the view helper methods in the question. However I was able to remove the bullets from the ul tags by using the following CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

The ul and li tags still remain, and I don't think there is currently a way to remove them using the world-flags gem unless you edit the gem yourself.

Hopefully this feature is added to future versions of the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a file in *config/initializers* directory (for example, "world_flags_config.rb") and put this code to that file? Make sure to reload your server after doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have added the above into an initializer called "world-flags.rb" do i need to wrap the code in anything because when I start my rails server I am getting the following error: 

"undefined method `flag_list_tag=' for WorldFlags:Module (NoMethodError)"

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a `div` instead of a `span`.

In `config/initializers/world_flags_config.rb` set the following:

```
WorldFlags.flag_list_tag = :div
WorldFlags.flag_tag = :div
WorldFlags.flag_text = ''
```

And in your views you could do this:

```
<div class="f32"><%= flag(:ar, "Argentina") %></div>
```